# Compactitem with /hfilled explanations!

Tags: itemize

I am currently working on a research project and have to hand in a thesis about it. In my paper, I need to use the `compactitem` environment with right-aligned explanations, which works fine so far (check MWE).

So, my question is: What if I need a multiline explanation? I want it to just show beneath Item2's explanation, without altering the space between Item2 and Item3. Is that even possible?

```
\begin{compactitem}
    \item Item A
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1 \hfill {\footnotesize Some explanation} 
        \item Item 2 \hfill {\footnotesize another explanation}
        \item Item 3 \hfill {\footnotesize yet another explanation}
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item B
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1 \hfill {\footnotesize ... and so on.}
    \end{itemize}
\end{compactitem}
```

[image: MWE]

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Stack the explanation, done here with right alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{compactitem}
    \item Item A
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1 \hfill {\footnotesize 
          \Longunderstack[r]{Some explanation\\requiring two\\ or more lines}} 
        \item Item 2 \hfill {\footnotesize another explanation}
        \item Item 3 \hfill {\footnotesize yet another explanation}
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item B
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1 \hfill {\footnotesize ... and so on.}
    \end{itemize}
\end{compactitem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, use a `\parbox` with top alignment (you define the width):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{compactitem}
    \item Item A
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1 \hfill {\footnotesize\parbox[t]{2in}{\raggedleft\lipsum[4]}} 
        \item Item 2 \hfill {\footnotesize another explanation}
        \item Item 3 \hfill {\footnotesize yet another explanation}
    \end{itemize}
    \item Item B
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1 \hfill {\footnotesize\ ... and so on.}
    \end{itemize}
\end{compactitem}
\end{document}
```

[image]